# How to register a window with the default cursor using LoadImage() instead of LoadCursor?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I can register a window class with the default cursor using:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
```

But after looking at the docs for LoadCursor here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursora

it says that "This function has been superseded by the LoadImage function"

What is the equivalent LoadCursor call to get the default arrow cursor?

Comment: `LoadCursor` is fine for the standard system cursors. If you want to load a custom cursor from your resources you usually want `LoadImage` to have more control over the size (although `LoadCursor` is usually fine for that as well, to be honest). I'm not sure that "superseded" message is really appropriate for this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew):

> **hInst**
>
> To load an OEM image, set this parameter to `NULL`.
>
> **name**
>
> To pass these constants to the `LoadImage` function, use the [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcew) macro. For example, to load the `OCR_NORMAL` cursor, pass `MAKEINTRESOURCE(OCR_NORMAL)` as the lpszName parameter, `NULL` as the hinst parameter, and `LR_SHARED` as one of the flags to the fuLoad parameter.

so just use the following code:

```
wndclass.hCursor = (HCURSOR) LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(OCR_NORMAL), IMAGE_CURSOR, 0, 0, LR_SHARED);
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work if `OEMRESOURCE` is defined before the windows headers